# Google spreadsheets: if cell contains one of a list of predefined values

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column in my spreadsheet that holds cells with strings of text like:

- *Lorem ipsum blah blah category1*
- *Lorem ipsum blah blah category2*

I want to have a second column that will hold values dependent on whether the string contains *category1*, *category2*, etc. I can do this with something like:

```
=arrayformula(if(H32:H="","",(iferror(if(search("category1",H32:H),"The First Category"),iferror(if(search("category2",H32:H),"The Second Category"))))))
```

However, the list of categories itself is dynamic, so rather than hard code them into the formula, I would like to retrieve them from elsewhere in the spreadsheet, ie:

```
| Category1 | "The First Category"  |
| Category2 | "The Second Category" | // I want to be able to add to this list and have the formula retrieve the values.
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could go about this?

EDIT: Please see sample sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tfIIQ1aNOi8CbiORXr6o4i30f4de5wR3L2bsvSdObAg/edit?usp=sharing). As you can see, the arrayforumula in A2 looks at the first 3 key values in E2 - E4, and gets the corresponding replacement values. However, I want to be able to add to the list of key/replacements without having to go and manually change the formula in A2 each time.

Comment: What about sharing an example spreadsheet with some data and the expected outcome ?

Comment: As you wish. Please see edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
=VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(C2,JOIN("|",INDIRECT("E2:E"&COUNTA(E:E)))),E:F,2,FALSE)
```

So to explain a little, the portion you see with the join function and indirect, is basically a dynamic regex, that will extend itself automatically (using the counta function) when you add new category types to your source list

So it does the Vlookup, to pull the value that matches a dynamic regex, and returns the corresponding index, "2"