# Google Sheets (Formula) - If one cell equals some value, it will return another value to a neighboring cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, formula, dayofweek, days

I am trying to find a formula for the following in Google Sheets:

- If a cell (C4) has the value Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun. I want it to return a number to a neighboring cell (B4) - the number 1 for Mon, 2 for Tue, 3 for Wed, etc.
- I have scoured the internet for this formula and have found nothing. Those who assist, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related:  [Google Sheets formula for "if contains"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95649/google-sheets-formula-for-if-contains), [Google spreadsheets: if cell contains one of a list of predefined values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649058/google-spreadsheets-if-cell-contains-one-of-a-list-of-predefined-values)

Answer (score 0):

try in B4:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(HLOOKUP(B4; REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(SEQUENCE(1; 7; 1000001); 
 {"ddd"; "@"}); "^100000"; ); 2; )))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(MATCH(B4; TEXT(SEQUENCE(1; 7; 1000001); "ddd"); )))
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to leave two answers? If so, it’d be useful to offer an explanation of when one option might be preferred over the other.

Comment: player0, What you have provided has resolved my issue. I have spent a little time looking into how the answer was acquired and plan on dissecting the formula further this weekend in order to further my learning. I am grateful for your assistance.